# How to place a button between start and centre position inside Framelayout?

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I have placed 3 buttons inside of Framelayout each with layout gravity as follows:

1. start|bottom
2. center|bottom
3. end|bottom

Now I want to place two additional buttons between (start and center) and (end and center). What is the best way to achieve this? I could not get 2 horizontal linear layouts on either side of center button to work and I don't intend to use BottomNavigationView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create 2 separate Linear Layouts one for either side of the center button. The left one should have

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

--add 2 buttons

</LinearLayout>
```

and the right one should have:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
--add 2 buttons

</LinearLayout>
```

The center button should be left intact in the Frame Layout.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use linear layout to achieve this. like: 
[image: this]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="First" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="two"
        tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="third" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fourth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="four" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fifith"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="fifith" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
why don't you use relative layout instead of frame layout. like this:
```

[image: Like this]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myapplication.MainActivity">

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/first"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/second"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fourth"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/third"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fifith"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fourth"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```